# How to avoid the ambiguous overloaded operator problem when using list and numeric vector in Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

## Goal

The code below is a very simplified version of my original code for creating a reproducible example. In this code, I am trying to generate a vector that is filled up by using 2 values in each iteration from a for-loop. These values are first multiplied with a parameter `p_BL` that I provide in a `parameters` list. You can see that at the end of the code I multiply the parameter (from a list) to a integer in a `NumericVector`. That's where I get the overloaded operator error. How can I resolve this?

## Code in the `simple_function.cpp` file

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector my_func(List parameters, int number_simulations)
{

  NumericVector vector_trig_times (number_simulations);
  NumericVector vector_trig_times1 (number_simulations);
  NumericVector vector_trig_times2 (number_simulations);


  for (int i_simulation = 0; i_simulation < number_simulations; i_simulation++) {

    int vector_activation1 = i_simulation + 2;

    int vector_activation2 = i_simulation + 5;



    vector_trig_times1[i_simulation] = vector_activation1;

    vector_trig_times2[i_simulation] = vector_activation2;



    vector_trig_times[i_simulation] = (parameters["p_BL"] * vector_trig_times2[i_simulation]) + ((1-parameters["p_BL"]) * vector_trig_times1[i_simulation]);

  } // i_simulations for loop


    return vector_trig_times;
}
```

### Compiling the file:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("simple_function.cpp")
```

## Error

[image]

Note: Line 28 refers to:

```
vector_trig_times[i_simulation] = (parameters["p_BL"] * vector_trig_times2[i_simulation]) + ((1-parameters["p_BL"]) * vector_trig_times1[i_simulation]);
```

## Edit: Text of the error message

```
C:/RBuildTools/3.5/mingw_64/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/durraniu/GOOGLE~1/DISSER~1"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c simple_function.cpp -o simple_function.o

simple_function.cpp: In function 'Rcpp::NumericVector my_func(Rcpp::List, int)':

simple_function.cpp:28:59: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'Rcpp::Vector<19>::NameProxy {aka Rcpp::internal::generic_name_proxy<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>}' and 'Rcpp::traits::storage_type<14>::type {aka double}')

     vector_trig_times[i_simulation] = (parameters["p_BL"] * vector_trig_times2[i_simulation]) + ((1-parameters["p_BL"]) * vector_trig_times1[i_simulation]);

                                                           ^

simple_function.cpp:28:59: note: candidates are:

In file included from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:136:0,

                 from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,

                 from simple_function.cpp:1:

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/complex.h:25:17: note: Rcomplex operator*(const Rcomplex&, const Rcomplex&)

 inline Rcomplex operator*( const Rcomplex& lhs, const Rcomplex& rhs) {

                 ^

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/complex.h:25:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'Rcpp::traits::storage_type<14>::type {aka double}' to 'const Rcomplex&'

In file included from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/operators.h:33:0,

                 from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/sugar.h:30,

                 from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:74,

                 from simple_function.cpp:1:

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/times.h:473:1: note: template<int RTYPE, bool LHS_NA, class LHS_T, bool RHS_NA, class RHS_T> Rcpp::sugar::Times_Vector_Vector<RTYPE, LHS_NA, LHS_T, RHS_NA, RHS_T> Rcpp::operator*(const Rcpp::VectorBase<RHS_RTYPE, RHS_NA, RHS_T>&, const Rcpp::VectorBase<RTYPE, RHS_NA, RHS_T>&)

 operator*(

 ^

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/times.h:473:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

simple_function.cpp:28:92: note:   'Rcpp::Vector<19>::NameProxy {aka Rcpp::internal::generic_name_proxy<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>}' is not derived from 'const Rcpp::VectorBase<RHS_RTYPE, RHS_NA, RHS_T>'

     vector_trig_times[i_simulation] = (parameters["p_BL"] * vector_trig_times2[i_simulation]) + ((1-parameters["p_BL"]) * vector_trig_times1[i_simulation]);

                                                                                            ^

In file included from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/operators.h:33:0,

                 from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/sugar.h:30,

                 from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:74,

                 from simple_function.cpp:1:

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/times.h:459:1: note: template<int RTYPE, bool NA, class T, class U> typename Rcpp::traits::enable_if<Rcpp::traits::is_convertible<typename Rcpp::traits::remove_const_and_reference<U>::type, typename Rcpp::traits::storage_type<RTYPE>::type>::value, Rcpp::sugar::Times_Vector_Primitive_nona<RTYPE, NA, T> >::type Rcpp::operator*(const Rcpp::sugar::NonaPrimitive<U>&, const Rcpp::VectorBase<RHS_RTYPE, RHS_NA, RHS_T>&)

 operator*(

 ^

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/times.h:459:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

simple_function.cpp:28:92: note:   'Rcpp::Vector<19>::NameProxy {aka Rcpp::internal::generic_name_proxy<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>}' is not derived from 'const Rcpp::sugar::NonaPrimitive<U>'

     vector_trig_times[i_simulation] = (parameters["p_BL"] * vector_trig_times2[i_simulation]) + ((1-parameters["p_BL"]) * vector_trig_times1[i_simulation]);

                                                                                            ^

In file included from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/operators.h:33:0,

                 from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/sugar.h:30,

                 from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:74,

                 from simple_function.cpp:1:

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/times.h:450:1: note: template<int RTYPE, bool NA, class T, class U> typename Rcpp::traits::enable_if<Rcpp::traits::is_convertible<typename Rcpp::traits::remove_const_and_reference<U>::type, typename Rcpp::traits::storage_type<RTYPE>::type>::value, Rcpp::sugar::Times_Vector_Primitive_nona<RTYPE, NA, T> >::type Rcpp::operator*(const Rcpp::VectorBase<RHS_RTYPE, RHS_NA, RHS_T>&, const Rcpp::sugar::NonaPrimitive<U>&)

 operator*(

 ^

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/times.h:450:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

simple_function.cpp:28:92: note:   'Rcpp::Vector<19>::NameProxy {aka Rcpp::internal::generic_name_proxy<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>}' is not derived from 'const Rcpp::VectorBase<RHS_RTYPE, RHS_NA, RHS_T>'

     vector_trig_times[i_simulation] = (parameters["p_BL"] * vector_trig_times2[i_simulation]) + ((1-parameters["p_BL"]) * vector_trig_times1[i_simulation]);

                                                                                            ^

In file included from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/operators.h:33:0,

                 from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/sugar.h:30,

                 from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:74,

                 from simple_function.cpp:1:

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/times.h:439:1: note: template<int RTYPE, bool NA, class T, class U> typename Rcpp::traits::enable_if<Rcpp::traits::is_convertible<typename Rcpp::traits::remove_const_and_reference<U>::type, typename Rcpp::traits::storage_type<RTYPE>::type>::value, Rcpp::sugar::Times_Vector_Primitive<RTYPE, NA, T> >::type Rcpp::operator*(const U&, const Rcpp::VectorBase<RHS_RTYPE, RHS_NA, RHS_T>&)

 operator*(

 ^

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/times.h:439:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

simple_function.cpp:28:92: note:   mismatched types 'const Rcpp::VectorBase<RHS_RTYPE, RHS_NA, RHS_T>' and 'Rcpp::traits::storage_type<14>::type {aka double}'

     vector_trig_times[i_simulation] = (parameters["p_BL"] * vector_trig_times2[i_simulation]) + ((1-parameters["p_BL"]) * vector_trig_times1[i_simulation]);

                                                                                            ^

In file included from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/operators.h:33:0,

                 from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/sugar.h:30,

                 from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:74,

                 from simple_function.cpp:1:

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/times.h:429:1: note: template<int RTYPE, bool NA, class T, class U> typename Rcpp::traits::enable_if<Rcpp::traits::is_convertible<typename Rcpp::traits::remove_const_and_reference<U>::type, typename Rcpp::traits::storage_type<RTYPE>::type>::value, Rcpp::sugar::Times_Vector_Primitive<RTYPE, NA, T> >::type Rcpp::operator*(const Rcpp::VectorBase<RHS_RTYPE, RHS_NA, RHS_T>&, const U&)

 operator*(

 ^

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/times.h:429:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

simple_function.cpp:28:92: note:   'Rcpp::Vector<19>::NameProxy {aka Rcpp::internal::generic_name_proxy<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>}' is not derived from 'const Rcpp::VectorBase<RHS_RTYPE, RHS_NA, RHS_T>'

     vector_trig_times[i_simulation] = (parameters["p_BL"] * vector_trig_times2[i_simulation]) + ((1-parameters["p_BL"]) * vector_trig_times1[i_simulation]);

                                                                                            ^

In file included from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Vector.h:58:0,

                 from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:40,

                 from simple_function.cpp:1:

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:271:14: note: template<int RTYPE, template<class> class StoragePolicy, class T> typename Rcpp::traits::enable_if<Rcpp::traits::is_convertible<typename Rcpp::traits::remove_const_and_reference<T>::type, typename Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy>::stored_type>::value, Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy> >::type Rcpp::operator*(const T&, const Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy>&)

              operator __OPERATOR__ (const T &lhs, const Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy> &rhs) {                                  \

              ^

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:280:1: note: in expansion of macro 'RCPP_GENERATE_SCALAR_MATRIX_OPERATOR'

 RCPP_GENERATE_SCALAR_MATRIX_OPERATOR(*)

 ^

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:271:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

              operator __OPERATOR__ (const T &lhs, const Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy> &rhs) {                                  \

              ^

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:280:1: note: in expansion of macro 'RCPP_GENERATE_SCALAR_MATRIX_OPERATOR'

 RCPP_GENERATE_SCALAR_MATRIX_OPERATOR(*)

 ^

simple_function.cpp:28:92: note:   mismatched types 'const Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy>' and 'Rcpp::traits::storage_type<14>::type {aka double}'

     vector_trig_times[i_simulation] = (parameters["p_BL"] * vector_trig_times2[i_simulation]) + ((1-parameters["p_BL"]) * vector_trig_times1[i_simulation]);

                                                                                            ^

In file included from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Vector.h:58:0,

                 from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:40,

                 from simple_function.cpp:1:

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:254:14: note: template<int RTYPE, template<class> class StoragePolicy, class T> typename Rcpp::traits::enable_if<Rcpp::traits::is_convertible<typename Rcpp::traits::remove_const_and_reference<T>::type, typename Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy>::stored_type>::value, Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy> >::type Rcpp::operator*(const Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy>&, const T&)

              operator __OPERATOR__ (const Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy> &lhs, const T &rhs) {                                  \

              ^

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:262:1: note: in expansion of macro 'RCPP_GENERATE_MATRIX_SCALAR_OPERATOR'

 RCPP_GENERATE_MATRIX_SCALAR_OPERATOR(*)

 ^

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:254:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

              operator __OPERATOR__ (const Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy> &lhs, const T &rhs) {                                  \

              ^

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:262:1: note: in expansion of macro 'RCPP_GENERATE_MATRIX_SCALAR_OPERATOR'

 RCPP_GENERATE_MATRIX_SCALAR_OPERATOR(*)

 ^

simple_function.cpp:28:92: note:   'Rcpp::Vector<19>::NameProxy {aka Rcpp::internal::generic_name_proxy<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>}' is not derived from 'const Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy>'

     vector_trig_times[i_simulation] = (parameters["p_BL"] * vector_trig_times2[i_simulation]) + ((1-parameters["p_BL"]) * vector_trig_times1[i_simulation]);

                                                                                            ^

simple_function.cpp:28:100: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator-' (operand types are 'int' and 'Rcpp::Vector<19>::NameProxy {aka Rcpp::internal::generic_name_proxy<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>}')

     vector_trig_times[i_simulation] = (parameters["p_BL"] * vector_trig_times2[i_simulation]) + ((1-parameters["p_BL"]) * vector_trig_times1[i_simulation]);

                                                                                                    ^

simple_function.cpp:28:100: note: candidates are:

In file included from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/date_datetime/date_datetime.h:29:0,

                 from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:62,

                 from simple_function.cpp:1:

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/date_datetime/Datetime.h:158:20: note: double Rcpp::operator-(const Rcpp::Datetime&, const Rcpp::Datetime&)

     inline double  operator-(const Datetime& d1, const Datetime& d2) { return d1.m_dt - d2.m_dt; }

                    ^

In file included from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/date_datetime/date_datetime.h:25:0,

                 from C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:62,

                 from simple_function.cpp:1:

C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/date_datetime/Date.h:164:19: note: double Rcpp::operator-(const Rcpp::Date&, const Rcpp::Date&)

     inline double operator-( const Date& d1, const Date& d2) { return d1.m_d -  d2.m_d; }

                   ^

make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf:215: simple_function.o] Error 1

Error in sourceCpp("simple_function.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

Comment: Please show the text of the error message instead of a picture of the text.

Comment: "code below is a very simplified version" but please make sure it still is a [mre]. I don't see any operator overload for example. Either the shown code is not an MRE, or it explains why the compiler does not see a matching overload for `*`  either.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I have added the text of error. I am getting this error when I run `sourceCpp("simple_function.cpp") `. `simple_function` is the name of the cpp file.

Comment: You have not shown any .cpp file. Please make a MRE.

Comment: I have put all the code in the `simple_function.cpp` file under the Code heading. And I have also explained that I'm getting the error after running `sourceCpp("simple_function.cpp")`. I hope the example is reproducible now.

Comment: I do not understand your description "running sourceCpp("simple_function.cpp")". Please make a MRE which demonstrates that by providing a `main()` function which does what you describe. That is how to make a MRE and it is a neccessary part of a question "why does this not work".

Comment: This code is written using `Rcpp` library in the `R` language. It does not require a `main()` function.

Comment: Because `Rcpp` enables the use of C++ in R. The error is occurring while compiling. It is essentially a C++ error.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know the type of the list element? I can't test right now but try converting the list element to a double value in your function.

Comment: Still, if the C++ compiler complains "no match for 'operator*'", then you should trace down where you expect the overload for that operator to be done for the used types. In contrast to what your title implies, you should work on that error first, because it is the first one. Errors tend to cause more errors, so the second error might indirectly be caused by the first.

Comment: Off-topic: Why do you need three vectors at all? The only value you ever use from two of the vectors are exactly the ones you placed in current loop run. So you could just use the two temporary variables and drop those two vectors entirely (unless your *unmodified* code used previous elements of the vectors, of course).

Comment: *'aka Rcpp::internal::generic_name_proxy<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>'* <-> *'aka double'* – obviously the proxy type does not provide an operator for multiplication with double. Most likely, you need to access some member of the proxy to get the value needed for multiplication out. Maybe you just need to dereference (`*parameters[...]`)? Peeking into rcpp's documentation should provide you the necessary information...

Comment: Have a look at [`get`](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/classRcpp_1_1internal_1_1simple__name__proxy.html#abfc353e1d6521e83a0b32268c39198ca)

Comment: `Rcpp::List` can contain any R object. The compiler has no chance to know if it can multiply the actual type in the end. I would create local variables of defined type for every element of the list before the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you could implement the spot-on suggestions of Roland and Ralf; notice I've also cut out the unnecessary vector creation and assignment for your `i+2` and `i+5` values (I also used `i` as a counter because I don't think `i_simulation` is more informative, so it makes your code less readable as the line either has to go way over 80 characters or you have to split the calculation over two lines):

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector my_func2(List parameters, int number_simulations)
{

    NumericVector vector_trig_times (number_simulations);
    double p_BL = as<NumericVector>(parameters["p_BL"])[0];

    for ( int i = 0; i < number_simulations; ++i ) {
        vector_trig_times[i] = (p_BL * (i + 5)) + ((1 - p_BL) * (i + 2));
    }

    return vector_trig_times;
}
```

This compiles just fine, and the result is as expected:

```r
Rcpp::sourceCpp("so.cpp")
my_func2(list(p_BL = 0.5), 10)
# [1]  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5 10.5 11.5 12.5
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not a regular user of C++, so this is really very helpful.